# Did the 'ptext' package disappear in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, package

One month ago I wrote some code for a simple game that depended on the 'ptext' package. Then I didn't touch it for some weeks and tried to play it now but got the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ptext'". When I tried to install it the package using conda install in my terminal, it told me that the package wasn't available. Can anybody tell me if I handled this situation wrong or what else I can do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never heard of such a module. And Google can't find it. Maybe it was something different but you accidently removed few chars and now it is only `ptext`

Comment: @furas It’s really weird, my code was running perfectly with 'import ptext' and within the first loop for example 'ptext.draw', but I couldn’t find anything now, either.

Comment: maybe you had `from something import ptext` or `import something as ptext`

Comment: Google couldn't find `ptext` but it found `ptext.draw` - [pygame-text](https://github.com/Flowdeeps/pygame-text)

Answer (score 1):

The module `ptext` doesn't exist in PyGame. See [PyGame - Docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/).
However, there is a GitHup repository [pygame-text](https://github.com/Flowdeeps/pygame-text) which implements a module `ptext`:

> This module simplifies drawing text with the `pygame.font` module. Specifically, the `ptext` module [...]